# How to use join together with dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have been working on a small projects where I have a counter to check if a characters reaches a specific number, then it will print it out on given count. If it doesnt reach the counter then we just print out the whole dicts.

I have done something like this:

```
payload = {'40': None, '42': None, '44': '6', '43': '3', '46': None, '45': '7', '51': None, '48': None, '47': None,
           '39': None}

characterCount, i = 0, 0
for j, item in enumerate(payload):

    if len(item) + characterCount > 5:
        print('\n'.join(payload[i:j]))
        characterCount, i = len(item), j
    else:
        characterCount += len(item)

if characterCount:
    print('\n'.join(payload[i:]))
```

I do have two problems.

1. This would probably work very well when using lists instead of dicts but yeah, thats not my options so I wonder if its possible to execute by calling indexes as I have done. I am fully aware that this will give an error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'` but I do not know if there is something similar way or maybe even better.
2. Also I would like to print the Key and Value (ONLY if value has a value, if it doesnt contain any value then we skip to print the `None`)

Is this sometihng that is possible to do?

EDIT:

This is how I used to do use before when I used Lists instead, however I have of course needed more knowledge where I need to store in key:value, Instead of having two lists where I store key and value for itself (There is probably better way) but I found that dict would be a better suite for me.

This is what I had before:

```
payload = ['40', '42', '44', '43', '46', '45', '51', '48', '47', '39']

characterCount, i = 0, 0
for j, item in enumerate(payload):

    if len(item) + characterCount > 5:
        print("Inside the if statement")
        print('\n'.join(payload[i:j]))
        characterCount, i = len(item), j
    else:
        characterCount += len(item)

if characterCount:
    print('\n'.join(payload[i:]))
```

---

Outprint

```
Inside the if statement
40
42
Inside the if statement
44
43
Inside the if statement
46
45
Inside the if statement
51
48
47
39
```

and this is what im trying to do but using dicts instead :)

Comment: Your problem is that you're using slices with dicts. What's that supposed to do `payload[i:]` if `payload` is a dict?

Comment: @baduker Not sure if I wasn't clear enough at the beginning, as I mentioned I have done  small function where I do a character counts, as we can see in this code `if len(item) + characterCount > 5:` meaning if the len of item and character count is more than 5, then we want ot print out `print('\n'.join(payload[i:j]))` So meaning that in our case it could be that it will then start from the index 3 and stop at index 5 as example. but as you mentioned we cannot use slices with dicts and here is one of my problems as I mentioned in the code below

Comment: I still don't get what you want to do here... Also, using `enumerate` and the slice notation `[:]` is *not* how you should work with a Python's dictionary data structure. [Here's a refresher on what you can do with a dict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

Comment: @baduker The point is that I want to print out the payload on given index with using `"\n".join(..)` but I do know that it is not possible as I can see and here I am :( Thats why I am asking as I do not have the knowledge to reach on how I can use the numerate and the slice notation with a dict as I did before. I can show you if you want a scenario with Lists, would that make more sense on what im trying to do?

Comment: Look, if you want to use `enumerate`, indexing, and slices **do not** use dictionaries.

Comment: You cannot use indices on dicts because they don't have any :-). If you must use a dict here, sort the keys to your liking and slice the resulting list. Something like `sorted(list(payload.keys()))[i:j]`. Not really pretty but I think that's want you want.

Comment: @baduker I have now updated my thread abit and maybe that would give a better view of what im trying to do. The missing part when using lists is that I do not have any values stored compare to the code I had at the beginning

Comment: @thisisalsomypassword haha nice name! I will check that for sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not quite understand what the point of the program is, but if I understood what you want to do it correctly, then you could use a filtered dictionary with key-value pairs that has value (not None).

```
print('\n'.join(list(filter(lambda k: payload[k] is not None, payload))))
```

Edit, here is an updated version, hopefully it's closer to what you're looking for:

```
payload = {'40': None, '42': None, '44': '6', '43': '3', '46': None, '45': '7', '51': None, '48': None, '47': None,
           '39': None}

characterCount, i = 0, 0
for j, item in enumerate(payload):
    if len(item) + characterCount > 5:
        selectedPayloads = ['{0} {1}'.format(k, payload[k]) for k in list(payload)[i:j] if payload[k] is not None]
        if len(selectedPayloads) != 0:
            print('\n'.join(selectedPayloads))
        characterCount, i = len(item), j
    else:
        characterCount += len(item)
```

Comment: Hey Kevin! I have now updated my question abit and not sure if that would give you better context as im still trying ti improve. In my head it sounded like I asked very good question but I was probably wrong :) But the code I tested with yours is not really what I was looking for as I also want to print out the values. Basically print everything, key:value but if value does contain None then just skip the None value (do not print the None)

Comment: In the example you are printing only the key. Would you like to print both the key and the value when the first if statement is reached? But only from i to j and as long as the value is not None?

Comment: You are correct regarding : `In the example you are printing only the key.` - thats due to I did not use any values as I was using dicts, it would looked pretty awful to do something like ```payload = ['40 None', '42 None ', '44 6 ', '43 3', '46 None', '45 7', '51', '48', '47', '39']``` so instead I want to convert to Dict instead.

Comment: Meaning that I would liek to print both the key and value IF there is a value (Meaning it should not contain the value `None`). The i to j is depending if the total characters have reached x amount of characters, in our example we check if the total characters is above 10, if it is then we use the i to j prints.

Comment: I updated it, hopefully I got you correctly.

Comment: Oh wow! This was beautiful! Was exactly what I was looking for! This was pretty cool!